# How to reposition Jetpack-media3/exoplayer control buttons?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using exoplayer2 via androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.0.0-beta03. I have a androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView in my XML layout, and then in my code I am creating an Exoplayer with ExoPlayer.Builder and assigning it to playerView.setPlayer.

The PlayerControls that are part of the player view feature a row of pause, skip forward, skip back buttons. They are displayed dead center, where they partially obscure the video. It feels very silly because the phone surface is probably very tall but the controls are in the center instead of the dead space.

There seem to be many appearance customization options in Exoplayer, but I don't find one to *move* the player buttons. In the old code (android.widget.MediaController/android.widget.VideoView) there was a similar row of buttons but they were at the bottom of the screen with a  small,pleasant margin underneath them. Am I missing something?

[Old appearance (good)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5zzW.png)
[New appearance (annoying)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcZO6.png)

Answer (score 5):

The centering appears to be a Jetpack Media3-specific thing. If you replace exo_player_control_view.xml with one from the base Exoplayer library, the controls move down to the bottom (but this will break other things).

If you want bottom controls with Media3, the best way I have found to do this is copy exo_player_control_view.xml out of whatever version of

https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/release/libraries/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_player_control_view.xml

...corresponds to your version of media3, and put it in your project at app/src/main/res/layout/exo_player_control_view.xml.

Then edit this file to change `@id/exo_center_controls` so that `android:layout_gravity="center"` becomes `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"`; also, add an attribute `android:padding="@dimen/exo_styled_controls_padding"`. After these changes I think maybe it would look better with a little bit more padding but that at least gets you in the ballpark.